# inconsistent asset precompiling Rails 4 and Heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

Recently upgraded to Rails 4.0.2 from 3.2 on Heroku.  I'm noticing that maybe every other push my `stylesheet_link_tag` and `javascript_include_tag` tags point to my development path (i.e. `/assets/admin.css`) instead of my production/precompiled @ fingerprinted path such as `/assets/admin-a334a2cf57ed6ffc29f7f7a1af35f380.css`

here are the relevant setting from production.rb:

```
# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = false

# Generate digests for assets URLs
config.assets.digest = true
```

Because I am on Heroku I have `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` in `application.rb`.  So I always run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` before deploying if I have made any changes to asset files.

Here is my folder hierarchy:

```
app
 -assets
   -images
   -javascripts
   -stylesheets
     -themes
       dark.css
       blue.css
       etc...
     admin.css
     application.css
     jobboard.css
```

here is my application.config

```
config.assets.precompile += [
    'admin.css',
    'admin.js',
    'jobboard.js',
    'jobboard.css',
    'themes/dark.css',
    'themes/blue.css',
    'themes/green.css',
    'themes/plain.css',
    'themes/seafoam-flat.css',
    'themes/fire-flat.css'
  ]
```

But for some reason I get this inconsistent behavior in production.  All files precompile.  But sometimes the admin.css file is not referenced w/ the fingerprint, same for the css files under /themes.  Any clue as to why this might happen?

Comment: Can you recompile your assets to see if there's a error or a missing file during the process?

Answer (score 0):

If there's a missing precompile file maybe you should add them in config/application.rb

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( admin.css )
```

and then

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

You can check in the manifest ( public/assets ) for missing file or to see the fingerprint.

Comment: Thanks.  I have all my files listed in config/application.rb.  Nothing is reported as missing.

Comment: Thanks. This issue isn't really that the are missing.  It's that sometime the correct/precompiled version is referenced, and sometime the development version is referenced.  When the dev version is referenced in production - it's not there and thus no css is rendered.

Comment: Is it a random file or always the same that is involved?

Comment: it's always the same few files - but it is randomly happening.

Comment: This post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697604/rails-assets-precompile-just-not-working?rq=1) suggests that heroku usually compiles assets directly. Maybe this make a conflict with your locally compiled assets?