# CSS not working on live heroku website but works on localhost

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, zurb-foundation

So I'm not even sure what code to show here, but I just have a basic Rails website using Foundation and hosted on Heroku. My CSS and everything has been working fine until one thing I added suddenly won't work after i pushed the changes to Heroku yet it is working on my localhost. This is the CSS that isn't working:

```
.thankyou {
    background-image: url('xxx.jpg');
    background-size:cover;

    a {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: underline;

        &:hover {

        }
    }

    .question-list {
        color: white;
        font-family: Muli;
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 17px !important;

        ul {
            list-style-type: none;

            li {
                font-size: 17px !important;
                line-height: 22px !important;
            }
        }

        p, ol, ul, td {
            font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 17px;
            line-height: 22px;
            color:white;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the HTML for that section:

```
<section class="hero thankyou">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
      <div class="main-wrapper">
      <h1>Thank you for your interest! </h1>
      <h3 id="putparadise"><em>Check your inbox for the link to the webinar, or click <a href="/">here</a> to return to the home page.</em></h3>

      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-8 columns webinar-video">
    <div class="black-box-2">
      <h3>6 critical questions that will be addressed in the webinar</h3>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-6 columns question-list">
          <ul>
            <li><p><strong>1. Type of title</strong><br> What kind of title are you getting? Is it a Land Title, a Conveyance or A Land Lease?</li></p>
            <li><p><strong>2. Taxation</strong><br> Capital gains taxes? Property taxes?</li></p>
            <li><p><strong>3. Water/Sewer</strong><br> Are the water and sewer regulated or unregulated?</li></p>

          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="large-6 columns question-list">
          <ul>
            <li><p><strong>4. Ownership Structure</strong><br> Learn about foreign ownership rights. Should you invest in your personal name vs company name vs IBC?</li></p>
            <li><p><strong>5. Vehicle Ownership</strong><br> Can I own a vehicle? Yes... IF your property meets the requirements for vehicle permits.</li></p>
            <li><p><strong>6. IRA/401K Eligibility</strong><br> Learn how you can use your retirement savings/funds to invest in Belize.</li></p>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 columns sidebar">
      <div class="black-box-3">
        <p><strong>After watching the on-demand webinar, you'll receive an email from us.</strong></p>

        <p>Simply reply to that e-mail if you'd like to receive more information,
          be sure to ask any specific question you have!
          We'll get back to you within 1 working day.</p>        
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 followup">
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

As far as I can tell there is no obvious errors in the heroku logs but I'm not great at reading them either so if anyone has any ideas about where to look or what might be going on that would be great!

Okay so after continuing to work on the project, I found out that the CSS I added for my newer section didn't work either. When i search 'cmd-f' for the code in the compiled CSS file in my project it is not coming up. What could cause the css to suddenly stop compiling?

Comment: Is it loading correctly the css file when you explore the source code of your page ?

Comment: @MaximeMangel
When I look at the compiled CSS that is on the live page none of the CSS i mentioned is there.. Why wouldn't it be pushing to heroku properly?

Comment: Did you used relative path or absolute path to reference your css files ?

Comment: So i found the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697604/rails-assets-precompile-just-not-working

Not sure which part of it solved the problem but it worked at least!

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following command in terminal

```
heroku run bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Then restart the server

```
heroku restart
```